# Regular expression works on RegularExpressionValidator but returns false on Regex.IsMatch

Tags: c#, webforms

I have the following RegularExpressionValidator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="Validator_alert" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
        ErrorMessage="Dit kodeord skal være mindst 6 tegn langt og indholde et tal, et stort bogstav og lille bogstav. Kodeordet må ikke indeholde tegnene &amp; og &#37;."
        ValidationExpression="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-z])(?!^[A-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9!@_:;+]{6,50})$"
        SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

And the following code behind to check the expression aswell:

```
string pattern = @"(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-z])(?!^[A-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9!@_:;+]{6,50})$";

                Boolean meetsRequirements = false;

                meetsRequirements = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(pattern, txtPassword.Value);
                meetsRequirements = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(pattern, txtPasswordRepeat.Value);

                return meetsRequirements;
```

Why does IsMatch return false, when the value in `txtPassword.Value` and txtPasswordRepeat.Value pass the test on the front end (RegularExpressionValidator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.IsMatch` takes 2 parameters - first one is input text, second one is pattern. You have incorrect order of parameters. Use:

```
string pattern = @"(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-z])(?!^[A-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9!@_:;+]{6,50})$";

Boolean meetsRequirements = false;

meetsRequirements = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtPassword.Value, pattern);
meetsRequirements = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtPasswordRepeat.Value, pattern);

return meetsRequirements;
```

And most probably you should check if both inputs are correct using:

```
meetsRequirements = 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtPassword.Value, pattern)
    && System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtPasswordRepeat.Value, pattern);
```